# How to find the name of a file received over JMS message (onmessage)

Tags: jms

How do we find the name of the file received through JMS message, i need to know the name of the file, for example if the text file of name example.txt is received, i want to get the name "example" of the file through javax.jms.Message.

here's the code

```
public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
    String msg = null; 
    if (message instanceof TextMessage || message instanceof BytesMessage) {
        if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {


            BytesMessage byteMessage = (BytesMessage) message; 
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer((int)byteMessage.getBodyLength());
          byteMessage.
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)byteMessage.getBodyLength(); i++) { 
                buffer.append((char)byteMessage.readByte()); 
            } 
            msg = buffer.toString().trim(); 
            //for processing the message i need to know the name of the file.
            //how to find the name of the file received, like "example" //if received file is "example.txt"
        }
        else  {
            getLogger().debug(this.getClass().getName() + ": Received TextMessage");
            msg = ((TextMessage)message).getText();
        }


    getLogger().debug("Request received by " + this.getClass().getName() + " has been processed");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]

Comment: @EngineerDollery updated with code.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thanks for the reply, I have updated the question with  example code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code. You can't get the filename unless it's sent as part of the message. In your example you seem to be receiving the file contents, which end up in your `msg` variable. Unless the sender somehow encodes the filename in the message (which is a bad idea for a text message), there is no way to find that information.

Answer (score 2):

JMS has no idea what a file is. Although, when sending the message, you can attach metadata to the message using string properties. It's common to place something like "originalFilename" as a property when the message is sent.

```
msg.setStringProperty("originalFilename",filename);
// .. set the bytes of the file somehow
msgProducer.send(msg);
```

then, in your receive code, you can just pick it up by

```
String filename = message.getStringProperty("originalFilename");
```